# Why aren't my images aligning correctly?

Tags: html, image, alignment

I'm trying to get 3 images next to each other with a little white space in between each one, I found the code online it works with the example code but it doesn't work for me? In the browser, the images are placed on top of another with big gaps in between.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head><title>pizza</title></head>

<body>
<h1 align="center"><font color="red" face="calibri">buy one get one free </font></h1>
<p align="center"><font color="black" face="calibri">order online for discount <span style="coloryellow">extra toppings,</span><span style="color:green"> stuffed crust</span> and<span style="color:green"> call now</span></font></p>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<div>
  <img src="pcrt1.png"></img>
  <img src="pcrt2.png"></img>
  <img src="pcrt3.png"></img>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the secret is called CSS -. which is used to style how your html elements behave...

Comment: Have you ever heard of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS will do the trick.

Have you tried, adding the style attribute?

```
<style>
img{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign "box" class to each of your image and add this css. Make sure your large images will not aligned automatically due to large size, so just you have to add the height of the images to work properly.

```
.box {display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 10px;}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I'm using an XSL stylesheet, I'm a little confused by the other suggestions where would I add the code?